# Use value in query to define the where of a sub query using sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am wanting to use the year column of the episode table to use in the where of the progress table with out doing two queries. Is this possible with Sequelize?

Here is the query I am running. Currently it is using a static year and I would like it to be dynamically generated based of the episodes year.

```
// Associations
models.Episode.belongsTo(models.Unit, {foreignKey: 'unitId', targetKey: 'unitId'})
models.Unit.belongsToMany(models.Badge, {through: 'unitToBadge'})
models.Badge.belongsToMany(models.Unit, {through: 'unitToBadge'})
models.Badge.hasOne(models.Progress, {foreignKey: 'badgeId', targetKey: 'badgeId'})

// Get Episode->Unit->UnitToBadge->Badge->Progress from episodeId
const episode = await models.Episode.findOne({
  where: {
    episodeId: episodeId,
    unitId: {
      [Sequelize.Op.not]: null
    }
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: models.Unit,
      include: [
        {
          model: models.Badge,
          include: [
            {
              model: models.Progress,
              where: {
                userId: userId,
                complete: false,
                year: 2019  // TODO need to get the year dynamicly from episode
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

This is the episode table model

```
const episode = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Episode = sequelize.define('episode', {
      episodeId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        unique: true
      },
      year: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      },
      unitId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
      },
      updatedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE(6),
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: sequelize.fn('NOW')
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE(6),
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: sequelize.fn('NOW')
      }
    }, {
      indexes: [
        {
          unique: false,
          fields: ['updatedAt']
        }
      ]
    })

    return Episode
  }

  export default episode;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unable to locate this case in the Sequelize docs.... strange because IMHO this is a relatively common occurrence.  Here is one solution:

```
where: { 
  userId: userId,
  complete: false,
  year: { $eq : Sequelize.col("episode.year")}   // set episode alias as needed
},
```

FWIW, although it is sensible, `year : Sequelize.col("episode.year")` did NOT work.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get `$eq` to work, but whenever I changed it to `[Sequelize.Op.eq]` it worked.